# passing a paremeter in a consumer to change context value

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I'm having a great difficulty with this for a few days. How does one change the context value in a nested component inside a provider wrapper.

For example:

The provider:

```
  <MapThemeContext.Provider value={this.state}>
    <div className="App">
      <Dashboard/>
    </div>
  </MapThemeContext.Provider>
```

where `this.state` (within the same component as the where the provider is rendered)

```
    this.state = {
      theme : themes.silver,
      handleMapChange: this.handleMapChange,
    }
    this.handleMapChange = (style) => {
      if (style == "silver") {
        this.setState({
          theme : themes.silver
        });
      } else if (style == "dark") {
        this.setState({
          theme : themes.dark
        })
      } 
    }
  }
```

And deep inside the provider (nested insside the `Dashboard`) is a consumer:

```
<MapThemeContext.Consumer>
  {({handleMapChange}) => (
    <div>
      <Button variant="contained" className={classes.button} onClick={e => handleMapChange('silver')}> // this does not work
        Silver
      </Button>
      <Button variant="contained" className={classes.button} onClick={handleMapChange}>
        Dark
      </Button>
    </div>
  )}
</MapThemeContext.Consumer>
```

How does the method call within the consumer use the correct parameter to set the value of the context?

Someone again deep down is another component that uses this context for the theme, and it does use the default value correctly. I just don't understand how to change it on the consumer button.

The context content:

```
export const themes = {
  silver: {
    foreground: '#000000',
    background: '#eeeeee',
  },
  dark: {
    foreground: '#ffffff',
    background: '#222222',
  },
};

export const ThemeContext = React.createContext(
  theme: themes.silver,
  handleMapChange: () => {},
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you replace below two section and check once.

```
----------------------------- Section 1 -----------------------------
const isTheme = this.state.theme;

let buttonName = "dark";
if(isTheme == "silver"){
    buttonName = "silver";
}

<MapThemeContext.Consumer>
    <div>
        <Button variant="contained" className={classes.button} onClick={handleMapChange}>{buttonName}</Button>
    </div>
</MapThemeContext.Consumer>

----------------------------- Section 2 -----------------------------

this.handleMapChange = () => {
      const style = this.state.theme;
      if (style == "silver") {
        this.setState({
          theme : themes.dark 
        });
      } else if (style == "dark") {
        this.setState({
          theme : themes.silver
        })
      } 
    }
}
```